# AppUpdateService Does not show that an update is available

Tags: java, android

AppUpdateService Does not show that an update is available. The application is added as production. When I install it on the device, it is not visible from the list of installed applications in google play? After starting the app, such a log:

```
I/PlayCore: UID: [10257]  PID: [13659] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.user.test)
I/PlayCore: UID: [10257]  PID: [13659] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
I/PlayCore: UID: [10257]  PID: [13659] AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
I/PlayCore: UID: [10257]  PID: [13659] AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can achieve this from one API's to call on app start first time. Here you can get your previous version of app so you can check and show the message if update available, this way not only update but also whatever you want to get dynamically you can use this way of store from page in admin or in database, but for this you need to manually or from admin page to store the app version in DB on every launch on play store.

This way can help you with current and previous version.